# finding cause of excessive memory usage in jvm 8

Tags: java, debugging, memory-leaks, jvm, java-8

My actual problem is this, currently netbeans is using about 4G (according to Activity Monitor on OS X) of memory. I've set several memory limiting options to no avail. from my `netbeans.conf`

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xmx1G -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
```

what I'd like to know is how can I find out why it's using this much memory? what steps should I take to determine the root source of the problem.

(I'm more interested in the generic than specifically netbeans). It may be worth noting that I've only been programming Java for a few months and don't know the tools available for this, or what things I should be checking for. (e.g. I added the MaxMetaspaceSize today because I realized that wasn't being limited, thinking that was probably it, but I'm still not sure how to check).

Here are some things I've found out from a visualvm heap dump

```
  File size: 364.7 MB      Total bytes: 332,921,516     Total classes: 24,143     Total instances: 4,151,139     Classloaders: 3,272     GC roots: 65,185     Number of objects pending for finalization: 0
```

it's metaspace graph showed it had reserved approximately 600M for the heap and 150M for metaspace. At that time Activity monitor was showing about 2G Memory usage. What I'm trying to figure out is where the entire 1G extra of memory usage is. If it were a few hundred more Megabytes it'd be tolerable, but 2-4G of ram is half the system memory (also noting that it doesn't behave this way on my Linux box, with the same versions). I'd think that anywhere from 800M-2G would probably be normal for a java IDE, and would be tolerable, and I wouldn't be investigating, it's this, use the rest of available memory, without any perceivable cause that makes me want to see what exactly, and why it's reserving this.

[image: Activity Monitor and visual VM numbers not adding up]

**Update:** this is a [Memory leak in Swing on OS X in JVM 8](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8041572)  I can't really accept answer that couldn't have gotten me to the point of locating the cause of the problem in jdk 8.

Comment: First step - find conditions under which memory consumption is unacceptable. This can be particular project or action, such as compiling, find usages, etc. Second step if you have no clues - profiling netbeans, but most likely you won't get any useful information. Also might be that your application opened in netbeans using some native code that is prone for memory leaks.

Comment: Define "using" specifically. It's not at all uncommon for an application to have mmapped in gigs' worth of shared libraries that 1) aren't actually resident and 2) are shared with lots of other running applications.

Comment: Also, how much does Activity Monitor show is used in each category of memory (active, inactive, etc)?

Comment: @MichaelBrewer-Davis (not 100% sure what you mean A.M. doesn't seem to have those names...) Real 2.83G, Shared 101.4M, Private 2.74G. currently, with 415/630M reserved by the Heap, 150/160M reserved for Metaspace, 23k classes loaded (500 unloaded).

Answer (score 2):

The JDK ships with tools.  Run %JAVA_HOME%\bin\jvisualvm.exe and examine your instance.  You should be able to perform a heapdump and analyze usage.

Comment: it tells me the heap is at about 600MB allocated and metaspace is about 150, which is significantly less than the 2.85 that is reportedly used by the OS... currently there's about 2G of memory unaccounted for.

Comment: Check the other running processes.  JVisualVM is not lying to you.

Comment: The only other running java process is JVisualVM... and OS X and visualvm agree with the process id of netbeans. Are these literally the only 2 places java could be consuming memory?

Comment: worth saying I don't think it's lying, but I don't think the OS is either because I usually end up swapping. So I'm thinking there must be more memory allocated elsewhere for some reason.

Comment: `File size: 364.7 MB

    Total bytes: 332,921,516
    Total classes: 24,143
    Total instances: 4,151,139
    Classloaders: 3,272
    GC roots: 65,185
    Number of objects pending for finalization: 0
`